# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connect() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\oophp\Home.php

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I tried linking my database with my php code and It got completed but tried in sending information to my database but it returns the fallowing error I tried it by creating an object and calling the method of the class but it returned me the error in the line I think there is a problem in calling the function but could not understand the error and even tried googling but could not solve the issue

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connect() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\oophp\Home.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oophp\Home.php(47): Home->__construct('example', 'example123', 'example8@gmail....') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oophp\Home.php on line 15

and the code in Connect.php is

```
<?php
class Connect
{

protected $connection;

public function __construct()
{

}
public function connect(){
    try
    {
        $this->connection = new 
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oo;charset=utf8mb4','root','');
        echo "connected sucessfully";
        return $this->connection;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "connection failed : " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
} 
?>
```

and code in Home.php is

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '\Connect.php'; 
class Home extends Connect{
protected $user = array();
protected $var0;
protected $response = array();
protected $username;
protected $password;
protected $email;
protected $var1;

public function __construct($username , $password ,$email)
{
    $var0 = new Connect();
    $var1 = $this->var0->connect();
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->email = $email;
}
public function Insert()
{
    try
    {
        global $var1;
        $insert = $this->var1->prepare("INSERT INTO person 
        (username,password,email) VALUES (:username,:password,:email)");
        $insert->bindParam(':username',$this->username);
        $insert->bindParam(':password',$this->password);
        $insert->bindParam(':email',$this->email);
        $insert->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }
        if(row_Count($insert)>0)
        {
            $this->response["status"] = 1;
            echo "Sucessfully inserted to database";
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response["status"] = 0;
            echo "there is a error in inserting";
}
}
}
$dfg  = new Home("example","example123","example8@gmail.com");
$dfg->Insert();
?>
```

I can't find the issue but I think there is an error at connect() function, thanks for any help

Comment: You're never defining `$this->var0` before you're trying to use it. Change `$var0 = new Connect();` to `$this->var0 = new Connect();`. Do the same for `$var1` in your constructor and remove the `global $var1` in your `Insert()`-method

Comment: Suggestion, make your property and variable names descriptive. Don't use generic names like `$var0`, `$var1` etc. You will thank me later on.

Answer (score 1):

change your `__construct` and remove `global $var1;`

```
public function __construct($username , $password ,$email)
{
    $this->var0 = new Connect();
    $this->var1 = $this->var0->connect();
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->email = $email;
}
```

Comment: but i think is there a need of passing the variables to the constructor ?

Comment: No need to pass variable in constructor if not required

Comment: I tried the above answer by Magnus Eriksson and got answer thankyou for the reply